# Using Colly framework I can't login to the Evernote account

Tags: go, web-scraping, evernote

I am using colly framework for scraping the website. Am trying to login the Evernote account for scraping some things. But I can't go through it. I used "username" and "password" titles for giving the credentials. Is this the right way ?.

Thank you in advance.

```
package main

import (
 "log"
 "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
 // create a new collector
 c := colly.NewCollector()

// authenticate
err := c.Post("https://www.evernote.com/Login.action", 
map[string]string{"username": 
  "XXXXXX@XXX.com", "password": "*********"})

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error : ",err)
}

    // attach callbacks after login
   c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
        log.Println("response received", r.StatusCode)
   })

    // start scraping
   c.Visit("https://www.evernote.com/")
}
```

Comment: I think evernote in first request should respond some headers with token or smthing like that, and then use them in next requests. Without that evernote has no idea who you are.

Answer (score 10):

You should try to mimic the browser behavior, take a look at this implementation, I've added comments on each step:

```
package evernote

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

const (
    evernoteLoginURL = "https://www.evernote.com/Login.action"
)

var (
    evernoteJSParamsExpr = regexp.MustCompile(`document.getElementById\("(.*)"\).value = "(.*)"`)
    evernoteRedirectExpr = regexp.MustCompile(`Redirecting to <a href="(.*)">`)

    errNoMatches   = errors.New("No matches")
    errRedirectURL = errors.New("Redirect URL not found")
)

// EvernoteClient wraps all methods required to interact with the website.
type EvernoteClient struct {
    Username   string
    Password   string
    httpClient *http.Client

    // These parameters persist during the login process:
    hpts  string
    hptsh string
}

// NewEvernoteClient initializes a new Evernote client.
func NewEvernoteClient(username, password string) *EvernoteClient {
    // Allocate a new cookie jar to mimic the browser behavior:
    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

    // Fill up basic data:
    c := &EvernoteClient{
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    // When initializing the http.Client, copy default values from http.DefaultClient
    // Pass a pointer to the cookie jar that was created earlier:
    c.httpClient = &http.Client{
        Transport:     http.DefaultTransport,
        CheckRedirect: http.DefaultClient.CheckRedirect,
        Jar:           cookieJar,
        Timeout:       http.DefaultClient.Timeout,
    }
    return c
}

func (e *EvernoteClient) extractJSParams(body []byte) (err error) {
    matches := evernoteJSParamsExpr.FindAllSubmatch(body, -1)
    if len(matches) == 0 {
        return errNoMatches
    }
    for _, submatches := range matches {
        if len(submatches) < 3 {
            err = errNoMatches
            break
        }
        key := submatches[1]
        val := submatches[2]

        if bytes.Compare(key, hptsKey) == 0 {
            e.hpts = string(val)
        }
        if bytes.Compare(key, hptshKey) == 0 {
            e.hptsh = string(val)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Login handles the login action.
func (e *EvernoteClient) Login() error {
    // First step: fetch the login page as a browser visitor would do:
    res, err := e.httpClient.Get(evernoteLoginURL)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if res.Body == nil {
        return errors.New("No response body")
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = e.extractJSParams(body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Second step: we have extracted the "hpts" and "hptsh" parameters
    // We send a request using only the username and setting "evaluateUsername":
    values := &url.Values{}
    values.Set("username", e.Username)
    values.Set("evaluateUsername", "")
    values.Set("analyticsLoginOrigin", "login_action")
    values.Set("clipperFlow", "false")
    values.Set("showSwitchService", "true")
    values.Set("hpts", e.hpts)
    values.Set("hptsh", e.hptsh)

    rawValues := values.Encode()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, evernoteLoginURL, bytes.NewBufferString(rawValues))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    req.Header.Set("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest")
    req.Header.Set("referer", evernoteLoginURL)
    res, err = e.httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    bodyStr := string(body)
    if !strings.Contains(bodyStr, `"usePasswordAuth":true`) {
        return errors.New("Password auth not enabled")
    }

    // Third step: do the final request, append password to form data:
    values.Del("evaluateUsername")
    values.Set("password", e.Password)
    values.Set("login", "Sign in")

    rawValues = values.Encode()
    req, err = http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, evernoteLoginURL, bytes.NewBufferString(rawValues))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    req.Header.Set("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest")
    req.Header.Set("referer", evernoteLoginURL)
    res, err = e.httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Check the body in order to find the redirect URL:
    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    bodyStr = string(body)
    matches := evernoteRedirectExpr.FindAllStringSubmatch(bodyStr, -1)
    if len(matches) == 0 {
        return errRedirectURL
    }
    m := matches[0]
    if len(m) < 2 {
        return errRedirectURL
    }
    redirectURL := m[1]
    fmt.Println("Login is ok, redirect URL:", redirectURL)
    return nil
}
```

After you successfully get the redirect URL, you should be able to send authenticated requests as long as you keep using the HTTP client that was used for the login process, the cookie jar plays a very important role here.

To call this code use:

```
func main() {
    evernoteClient := NewEvernoteClient("user@company", "password")
    err := evernoteClient.Login()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason even with passing cookie to the client I get `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error